# DC Shunt Generation Ascending/Descending Terminal voltage Saturation Curve help?

Tags: dc, generator, saturation, shunt

In a DC Shunt Generator we increased Field Current from 0 to 2.0 and calculated the Terminal Voltage, we then decreased field current from 2.0 to 0 and collected our field current again. When plotting the data of ascending and descending field voltage on a saturation curve why does the descending portion of the curve lie above the ascending portion?

Answer (score 1):

That's magnetic hysteresis.

The iron in the field core retains its magnetic field even when you reduce the current in the field windings.

[Hysteresis](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/hyst.html)